# Konvajs: Transformer's method rotateEnabled() working incorrectly

Tags: konvajs

Creating Transformer with `rotateEnabled: false` parameter is works fine. It totaly remove rotate handle and other. But if disable rotation by `transformer.rotateEnabled(false)` method - rotation handle's line disappear, but handle stay on the stage and CAN rotate node. Look jsfiddle for example.

https://jsfiddle.net/Feaman/d8aufzsk/19/ - with `rotateEnabled(false)` method
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/Feaman/d8aufzsk/20/ - with `rotateEnabled: false` parameter
[image]

Comment: Workaround by @VanquishedWombat works good. But it still the bug in Konva. It is already fixed and will be published in the next version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: May 2022 - the Transformer.attachTo and setNode are, according to the docs 'deprecated and will be removed soon'.  The official way to attach a transformer to nodes is via the [Transformer.nodes()](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Transformer.html#nodes__anchor) method into which you pass an array of the nodes to be connected to the transformer.

This means that the code example for creating the transformer independently and adding the nodes to it would be

```
  const tr = new Konva.Transformer({});
  tr.rotateEnabled(false)
  tr.nodes([image]);
```

[Original answer]

I concur that the issue is present in your fiddle.

Call tr.setNode(image); to ensure the transformer is updated - see  [jsfiddle.net/o7r3jnfy](http://jsfiddle.net/o7r3jnfy)

```
  const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
    node: image
  });
  tr.rotateEnabled(false)
  tr.forceUpdate();
```

Another workaround is to  create the transformer without referring to it's node, then  call tr.attachTo(); immediately after tr.rotateEnabled(false) - see [jsfiddle.net/rf572nut](http://jsfiddle.net/rf572nut)

```
  const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
    //    node: image
  });
  tr.rotateEnabled(false)
  tr.attachTo(image);
```

Alternatively, also create the transformer without referring to it's node, then add tr.setNode(image); to attach to the shape 'after' the transformed is created. See fork of your example http://jsfiddle.net/638hmcjn/. Looks like this:

```
  const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
  //    node: image
  });
  tr.rotateEnabled(false)
  tr.setNode(image);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. It will help. So, it's appear to be a bug?

Comment: If you want to raise it as an issue I guess you should do so at github.com/konvajs/konva/issues.